# Why is fontconfig so slow when using user defined fonts?

Tags: fonts

In order to use some LaTeX templates I copied over some fonts from a MacBook to my Dell XPS 13 (with default installation of Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS). I'll only use these templates occasionally, but I thought it can't hurt to have these fonts available for other applications.

But ever since I experience a really slow startup of about 15s of basically every application which uses the fontconfig library.  Even a simple `fs-list` takes this long. Of course I already executed `fs-cache -fv` several times and even generated `fonts.dir` and `fonts.scale` files but to no avail.

I first put these fonts into `~/.fonts` then into `~/.local/share/fonts` after I learned the former directory is deprecated and finally into `/usr/local/share/fonts` after I learned that some systems have problems with generating cache files for user fonts, but the issue stays the same.

I can see cache files in `~/.cache/fontconfig` and `/var/cache/config` with appropriate read permissions. But the problem also occurs when I start an application with admin rights, so a permission problem is unlikely .

The only way to get rid of the problems is to remove the fonts again (i.e. keeping them in a directory not known by fontconfig). But that makes me wonder if I'm missing something since I don't think this should be a problem?

When using `strace` the calls wich seems to slow things down during an application startup seem to be of this kind:

```
stat("/usr/local/share/fonts/Arial Black.ttf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=122556, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/local/share/fonts/Arial Black.ttf", O_RDONLY) = 4
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=122556, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 122556, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 4, 0) = 0x7f0ac8cab000
close(4)                                = 0
```

As you can see the file is not only opened but also loaded and mapped into memory, which doesn't seem to make sense since this doesn't happen for preinstalled fonts. It seems this is happening for every user font of which I have about 280 which surely would explain the slowdown.

The fonts I copied are mostly `.ttf` and `.ttc` with some `.otf` and a few `.dfont`.

Somebody knows what I'm missing?

Comment: Hey, 5 years on im having this issue when first starting up chrome.. did you get anywhere with it, if you can remember!?

Comment: Good question! As far as I remember, I just left these extra fonts in a place where LaTeX could find them, but not in a shared font directory to avoid the slowdown problem. Unfortunately, my Dell currently doesn't boot up anymore, so I can't verify if I did some other tweaks. In any case, I still would like to get an answer to my question.